# Object file directory per compiler option combinations

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was reading gnu make section 10.5.4 "How patterns match" and it does not sound like I can do what I want.

I want to setup a directory structure where my source code is in one directory, and there are sub-directories to hold object files.
One sub-directory for each build configuration.
So I might have these files

```
a.c
debug/a.o # compiled with -g
release/a.o # compiled with -O
```

So I would like to make rules like this

```
debug/%.o : %.c
    gcc -c -g %.c -o $@

release/%.o : %.c
    gcc -c -O %.c -o $@
```

But section 10.5.4 tells me a match on "debug/a.o" will make the stem be "debug/a" so gnu make
will look for the source file at "debug/a.c" which is not what I want.

Is there a way to get GNU make to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile will work as written.

From [that section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match):

> **When the target pattern does not contain a slash** (and it usually does
>   not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name
>   before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the
>   comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory
>   names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the
>   prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule's prerequisite
>   patterns... [bold added]

Your target patterns *do* contain slashes.

Try it if you don't believe me.

**EDIT:**

Correction: in the commands you should use `$<` rather than `%.c`.

Comment: % does not seem to work in the rule, but other wise you were right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
CC=gcc
DEBUGFLAGS=-g
RELEASEFLAGS=-O
debug/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

release/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(RELEASEFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```