# How to compile a second version of a program from the same source using GNU Make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I want to compile a second version of my program from the same source (using `#ifdef TESTS`, etc.), that is:

```
prog.cpp --(compile)--> prog-tests
```

I can realize this with the following `Makefile` rules:

```
prog-tests: prog.cpp
       $(LINK.cpp) -DTESTS $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

or

```
prog-tests: CPPFLAGS += -DTESTS
prog-tests: prog.cpp
        $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

*Which of this versions is to be preferred/the best practice?* I want to use implicit rules as much as possible.

(I am using GNU Make 4.0.)

Comment: It is a matter of taste. I prefer the second version. And very often, programs are built from *several* translation units. Then you might want `foo.debug.o` for debug variant, and `foo.o` for release variant

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568244/object-file-directory-per-compiler-option-combinations for another approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to compile the same source file into object files using different compiler flags, these object files must be produced into different directories.

However, your command lines skip the object file creation as they compile and link in one step (no object files are produced). So, there is little difference in how you add the extra compiler flags here.